# convert python StringIO to BufferedReader

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using two different libraries. One gives out a stream as [StringIO](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html#module-StringIO). Another library expects a File like object and invokes read method on it. I don't want to persist the stream to a tempfile, to avoid disk IO operations.

Is there a way to create a [BufferedReader](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#buffered-streams) from StringIO object ?
Is there a different approach to handle this problem ?

Environment details : Python 2.7

Comment: `StringIO.StringIO` is already a file-like. How exactly is your code failing?